Flyway: run script-based migration
In Flyway documentation I found that it supports migration script not only in SQL format, but also as PowerShell, Bash, Python etc. formats (Flyway docs)
And found an example that it should be possible to use migrations like this:
V1__create_table.sql
V2__alter_table.sh

But testing it using flyway command line tool I see that Flyway always skips any other file extension except .sql
Here is my command:
flyway migrate info -url=jdbc:sqlserver:DB_URL -locations=filesystem:"/Users/blabla/repos/flyway” -user=“USERNAME” -password=“PASSWORD” -defaultSchema=“yes”t -table="flyway_schema_history" -cleanDisabled="true" -baselineOnMigrate="true" -baselineVersion="0.0.1"

AmI doing something wrong?
Flyway CLI version is Flyway OSS Edition 10.17.0 by Redgate

Problem was solved updating Flyway to version 10.17.1
In release notes for this version was written:

Script migration is now available as an open source feature of Flyway

Seems that before it this feature was disabled for non-paid usage
